# Output block content from controller

Tags: magento2

I am trying to use sections.xml to return some data(customerData) upon user login. What i want to do is to return customer navigation links in customerData. And i thought that i can achieve this with sections.xml. But i face the problem when trying to load the **customer_account_navigation** block that actually has those links.

Ok, so i made a module AccountNavigationLinks which has CustomerData directory with .php file. This file has **getSectionData** method.

```
public function __construct(
    Session $session,
    \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory

)
{
    $this->session =$session;
    $this->resultLayoutFactory = $resultLayoutFactory;
    $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
}

public function getSectionData()
{
    $layout = $this->layoutFactory->create();
    $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('customer_account')->load(['default']); // i think i need to add this handle. but still unsure of load which handle should i pass into load method
    $layout->generateXml();
    $layout->generateElements();
    $data = $layout->getBlock('customer_account_navigation')->toHtml();
    return ['links'=> 'dome data']; // here i want to return an array of links or whatever i can get from account_navigation_links

}
```

So, i want to have that **customer_account_navigation** block in my response and then i will, hopefully, get those links. But i can't get that block in my **$layout**. How can i get those links returned anyway?

Hope to find some help.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you managed to do this? I try to do the same thing

Comment: @VladPatru i posted answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the wrong classes in my constructor. Instead of using 

`\Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory,
\Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory` in constructor,

use `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory`.

Then add handles you need and fetch the block:

```
$resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
$resultPage->addHandle(['default', 'customer_account_index']);
$block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('customer_account_navigation');
$data = $block->getBlockHtml('customer_account_navigation');
```

Comment: Good work man, thanks. Works like a charm